# Using Trusted Web Activity to link multiple websites with native application

Tags: android-studio, trusted-web-activity

I've managed to link my native application to a website and launch the same on a button click. As the website is trusted, the URL bar is not visible. In the launched website there is a button which then further redirects to another website. I've created a digital asset link for both and have added the JSON file in `<websitename>/.well-known/<json-file>`.

Both the websites have also been referenced in `strings.xml` under
`asset_statements`. However, on launching the first website and then redirecting to the second website from the first, the second website launches as a regular custom chrome tab with the URL bar visible.

Is it possible to hide both the URL's? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

To enable multi-domain, you need to check 3 things

- Each origin has a `.well-known/assetlinks.json` file
- The android `asset_statements` contains all origins
- Tell the Trusted Web Activity about additional origins when launching.

It seems you have the first two points covered, but not the last one.

### Using the support library LauncherActivity:

If using the LauncherActivity that comes with the library, you can provide additional origins by updating the AndroidManifest:

1. Add a list of additional origins to `res/values/strings.xml`:

```xml
<string-array name="additional_trusted_origins">
    <item>https://www.google.com</item>
</string-array>
```

2. Update `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">


    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.ADDITIONAL_TRUSTED_ORIGINS"
        android:resource="@array/additional_trusted_origins" />


    ...
</activity>
```

### Using a custom LauncherActivity

If using your own LauncherActivity, launching with additional origins can implemented like this:

```java
public void launcherWithMultipleOrigins(View view) {
  List<String> origins = Arrays.asList(
      "https://checkout.example.com/"
  );


  TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder builder = new TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder(LAUNCH_URI)
      .setAdditionalTrustedOrigins(origins);


  new TwaLauncher(this).launch(builder, null, null);
}
```

## Resources:

- Article with more details here: https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/multi-origin
- Sample multi-origin implementation: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/twa-multi-domain

Comment: <activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"> 
Please confirm, if the above tag is required only if we are launching the website as our main activity and wouldn't be required in the scenario where we are launching via the MainActvity on a button interaction?

Comment: Yes, that's required - the `LauncherActivity` is started when the application is launched from the home screen and it's only purpose is starting the Trusted Web Activity

Comment: But if I want to launch the app first and only during a button click on a layout would I want to start TWA in that case I wouldn't be adding LauncherActivity right? From what I understand Launcher activity is used when you to launch TWA right for the home screen.

Comment: Right. That's the  "Using a custom LauncherActivity" section. There's a sample here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/blob/master/demos/twa-custom-launcher/src/main/java/com/google/androidbrowserhelper/launchtwa/LaunchTwaActivity.java#L118-L131